# Solving unit vectors equations

Tags: vectors

Let u and v be unit vectors. Prove that u+v is perpendicular
to u − v.

What I did is:

Since they are unit vectors: $|u|$=$|v|$=1

If they are perpendicular, then $(u+v)$.$(u-v)$=$0$

Ans: $|u+v|$.$|u-v|$.$\cos\theta$

= (1+1).(1-1).$\cos\theta$

=$0$

proved.

Is this right?

Comment: $$|u-v| \neq |u| - |v|$$

Comment: No, because |u - v| is not |u| - |v| which you have assumed here. You need to note that $u.u = |u|^2$ to get it right.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not right, because $|u+v|$ is not $|1+1|$.

Try this, instead:
$$(u+v)\cdot(u-v)=u\cdot u+u\cdot v-v\cdot u-v\cdot v=\ldots$$

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'm new to vectors and they seem difficult to me. Could you please complete your answer?

Comment: For a unit vector $u$, product $u\cdot u$ is $1$. The same is true for $v\cdot v$. So, it remains to be shown that $u\cdot v - v\cdot u$ is in fact $0$.

Comment: @MohamedAl-Qabtan Just remember that $|u|^2 = u \cdot u$.